Automatically prevent the posting of some non-helpful comments/answers
I notice there are a lot of non-helpful comments and answers. I’d imagine a lot of those could be automatically prevented by disallowing comments/answers that have no words other than a certain set of phrases. Here are some phrases that I think would make sense, although I’d imagine there might be some others that would be helpful.

Thank you/Thank you very much/Thanks/etc.
Did you solve this yet?/Is this fixed?/Did you ever figure this out?/Do you have any suggestions?/etc.
Curse words.
(Answers only) Links/URLs.
@(username of someone who has asked/commented/answered the question
I can’t add comments/I am unable to post this as a comment/etc. (Answers only)

Hopefully this would still detect it if the words were obfuscated and different fonts, capitalization, etc. I can’t imagine a single false positive here, and I can imagine many bad posts it would catch. Could this be implemented?
To clarify, only posts that have no words other than the above phrases would be prevented. If a comment has “thank you so much” in it and then other stuff, it can be posted. Only if it’s sole content is “thank you so much” will it be prevented.

The solution that exists is to make (almost all) of these comments eligible for deletion if flagged by even one user, rather than requiring multiple comment flags to remove. It allows them to be posted (as they aren't always problematic) but also makes it easy to remove them.

@Catija could you find me one post which is solely the above phrases that is a useful post anywhere on the network, because I can’t think of any post that is solely links, curses, thanks, variations of did you fix this, and “@user” that would be good

Pr0blemz solved...

The problem with blocking things like this is that a substantial percentage of people will just keep trying alternate versions of the same comment until they find something that the system allows them to post. Yes, blocking will block some, but people tend to be persistent and we can't account for all permutations/combinations. You seem to recognize that people will do this by asking for the system to detect obfuscation and different Unicode fonts.

@Makyen Yes, this is the exact point…people can find workarounds,  but the majority of those can be banned as well. Also, if this blocked 60% of people who were going to post something like that, that is still good, is it not?

... I didn't say "post" - I specifically said comments.

@Starship I know we are (or at least SO is) portrayed as an unwelcoming communities, but banning users for saying thank you?! Existing system is sufficient, imo. If a 'thank you' comment is cluttering comment section, someone will flag it and it will get deleted. BTW, more than 60% of people will bypass those filters, based on my personal experience.

@Catija okay, find a useful comment that is solely curse words, at replies, and thank you/did you solve this

We tried that with titles. The word problem is banned in titles for example, that's why you see lots of posts with probelm in the title. We also don't want to end up with a Scunthorpe problem.
All you'll get are lots of comments with deliberate misspellings to get around the block. Block the misspellings and you'll get other misspellings in a pointless and unwinnable game of whack-a-mole. Block only comments which exactly match and they will either be deliberately misspelled e.g. "Thnak you", or you'll get nonsense at the end e.g. "Thank you XXXXXXXX"
A better solution might be to expand the words that make a comment 1 flag deletable but we might end up throwing the baby out with the bath water if we do too much of that i.e. comments might end up too easily deleted. Most curse words and words like thanks and thank you are already in the 1 flag delete category.

Yet again, please find 1 example of a comment or answer that is made solely from the above phrases that shouldn’t be deleted.

that's completely beside the point. Why encourage people to misspell words because that's all blocking will accomplish.

I think if you give a message stating that “this type of post is not allowed, see this” it will as least stop some people. And if you are saying it might block legitimate posts, then I am challenging you to actually find a single example out of nearly 100 million posts on this network (and that’s not even going into comments) that would be incorrectly stopped by this.

Blocking problem in titles didn't so I have evidence it's pointless. I'm saying it will block nothing because everyone will just work around it.

This would be closer to blocking titles that are solely “I have a problem”. Unlike just the word problem, which one could legitimately put in a good title, that should never be the entire title

@Starship I've definitely seen some of those overly ass-kissy comments that go like "Thank you for your good question + response to the clarification that was actually asked for". I'm not going to hunt them down, but its definitely not something that should be blocked outright even though it is very annoying to be treated like a preschooler that asked a question during show and tell when you ask for clarification. As long as the clarification is provided...

How is that even related, I’m not proposing to block those. Only comments which have nothing but the above phrases (or some combination) of them, @Tinkeringbell

Some but not all. There is a minimum body length too, which some people add nonsense to avoid, should that be removed? @RobertLongson

@RobertLongson what comment, where?

@RobertLongson yes, it won’t stop everyone, but it will hopefully stop a reasonable amount

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Starship Well "thanks" alone is already blocked as it isn't 15 characters, and comments need to be 15 characters. So, it's reasonable to assume you're talking about comments containing more than that.

“@Tinkeringbell thanks” isn’t however though. That is an example of a comment that could be easily prevented with no false positives

"@Starship I see your example. It still hasn't changed my opinion that this is in any way easily prevented. Thanks". > Something like that is still not easily and validly blocked by a simple rule like "@*. Thanks".

@Tinkeringbell but that comment contained something useful

@testing-for-ya no it wouldn’t, because that comment has words other than “@“ and “thanks”

@testing-for-ya only if it the display name of someone who asked/answered/commented on the questiion. And by the way, today alone I’ve flagged something like 5 answer and 15 comments that could probably fall under something like this proposal today alone.

Read what I added in bold text. I can’t imagine a single FP@testing-for-ya

I flag quite a lot of comments of the type you want to block as "no longer needed" and I don't think that these comments are in themselves such a bad thing.
Very often, a simple "thank you" type comment comes at the end of a discussion between two users and, as mentioned in another answer to this question, they can usually be removed by flagging and they immediately disappear without the need to bother a moderator.
However, I normally read the previous comments to see if they are still necessary. For example, there may be three or four comments earlier discussing and then requesting an edit and then one of the users will thank the other. For me, these simple "thank you" type comments are clues that some other longer and more convoluted comments can also be deleted -- because, for example, I now know that it is worth hunting through the edit history to see if the post was edited accordingly.
Sometimes, there is a single "thank you" type comment by a question asker with an indication that an answer was useful, and no green tick or upvote on the answer. In these cases, I would always leave those comments. However, if the answer was upvoted three or more times, then I might be tempted to flag such a comment.
Forcing users to communicate in a more convoluted way would make cleaning up comments more difficult.
